# Equivalent of itemgetter in golang

Tags: python, go

I'm converting a program from python to golang, and I have this line that gets the first value within a nested list:
`x_values = map(operator.itemgetter(0), self.coords)`
This command turns `[[1,2],[2,3],[7,4]]` to `[1,2,7]`.

Is there an equivalent of this in go?

Comment: It's not a natural one-liner in go. Is that your question? You'd construct `x_values` using a for loop.

Comment: That was my question.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent in Go would be a `for` loop:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := make([][]int, 3)
    a[0] = []int{1, 2}
    a[1] = []int{2, 3}
    a[2] = []int{7, 4}

    b := make([]int, len(a))
    for i, v := range a {
        if len(v) > 0 {
            b[i] = v[0]
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/pNz8nQu20D